# RDD, PySpark, Why rdd.flatMap seems does not do any operation in CPU?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Show my code

```
In [10]: rdd = sc.mongoPairRDD("mongodb://localhost/stackoverflow.stack")

......
     A lot of INFO
......    

In [11]: newrdd = rdd.flatMap(f)

# No INFO

In [12]: newrdd.collect()
# A lot of INFO
```

When a function of `rdd` was call, say `flatMap`, it seems the system doesn't run the code of the function. But when, say call `collect()`, the system runs and collect all the data from memory or disk?

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are! It is actually the expected behavior for Spark. There are *transformations* (eg map, flatMap, reduce) and *actions* (count, collect, saveAsTextFile) that you can apply to an RDD.

As you noted, when you call a transformation, no computation happen, it just stacks the operation to the RDD to get some kind of recipe to produce it. But as soon as you call an *action* then boom, the RDD is actually evaluated. This is what happens when you call collect.